# How to get float value from string using regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, match

I have a string value that will look like this:

```
"ZAR 200.15"
```

Using regex, how can I extract the float value to do calculations with?

For some context, I'm using javascript to access an HTML element's value like this:

```
var amountDueString = document.getElementById("amountDue").innerHTML;
```

Then I need to use regex to only get the float value.

```
var amountDue = amountDueString.match(---some regex---);
```

I want to extract the float value in order to compare it with user input.

Comment: Match `/\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(\d)+\.(\d+)
```

tested on notepad++

Comment: Thanks. Using this regex along with parseFloat(), I got the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Use regular expression to get number string and then use parseFloat to convert it to floating number

```js
for (var x in arr = ["ZAR 200.15", "20.0", "21", "22.2", "22.20"]) {
  // decimal part only
  console.log(parseFloat(arr[x].match(/(\d+)(\.\d+)?/g)))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**[Working example](https://regex101.com/r/lL3uA2/1)**.

I think the better way is the one commented by @anubhava :

> /\b\d+(?:.\d+)?/

**`\b` :** assert position at a word boundary *(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)*.

**`\d+` :** match a digit [0-9],
**`Quantifier +`** Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy].

**`Quantifier ?`** Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy].

**`\.`** matches the character . literally

Hope this helps.

```js
console.log( "ZAR 200.15".match(/\b\d+(?:.\d+)?/) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match number with decimals only or numbers with integer and decimal parts:

```js
for (var x in arr = ["ZAR 200.15", "300.0", "1.02", "29.001", "10"]) {
  // decimal part only
  console.log(x, arr[x].match(/(\d+)(\.\d+)?/g))
    // integer + decimal part
  console.log(x, arr[x].match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex to find the floating number and then replace all the other word chars.

```
var str = "\"ZAR 200.15\"";
var patt = /[^(\d+)\.(\d+)]/g;
var string = str.replace(patt,"");
window.alert(string);
```

checkout here: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/59ymwvq9/)